# Add a prefix to a randomly generated string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my erb file I have this:

```
"name": "<%= o =*('a'..'z'),*('A'..'Z')
             string = o.sample(10).join %>",
```

That assigns a random generated string as the value to the `name` element as the key.

It is generating the random string fine but in `RubyMine IDE` it says

```
"expected <% or <%= or ;"
```

at the place of the second `"*"` in the code?  Why is that and how to fix it?

Also more importantly, How can I can a prefix to this generated string? so for example let's say this generates string of `abcDef`  But I need it to be `MyPrefix_abcDef`

Comment: manupulate string like <% string = code %> then
<%= "name_#{string}" %>

Comment: Ok, why does it warn me about the first line of code under the "*" ? anything wrong with that? or just IDE is crazy?

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for a helper method. This seems too complex to be in the view

Comment: This is not in the view. It is a .json.erb file

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this was a rails project and this was in the `views` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE is correct, there is an error. You need to replace

```
o =*('a'..'z'),*('A'..'Z')
```

with

```
o =[*'a'..'z'] + [*'A'..'Z']
```